# ISP Router's Wi-Fi "Lags" after a few days

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

My ISP's ONT+Router have this weird this where it makes Wi-Fi kinda unresponsive.

It will ping fine. It will be just as fast as it should be. However, websites will open late and some apps will work really sluggishly.

If I connect my TP-Link router with it in "Router" mode where it simply shares the Internet and my router also manages all the features like NAT, DHCP etc., everything remains snappy.

However, if I connect my router to ISP's router in Access Point mode, in which it only shares the internet and everything else is managed by the ISP router, it also slows down after a few days.

I thought my ISP's router have some hardware issues due to which it causes issues in Wi-Fi but not in Ethernet.

So, what do you think could be causing these issues.

P. S. Please do remember, it got nothing to do with interference.

Comment: This is caused by dodgy software on the router and is (or at least used to be) very common on low end routers. Often tjis relates to bad "connection tracking" for NAT and multiple devices - putting a second router behind it means it only needs to track 1 device and it works better.  If the router/ONT can be flashed with an alternative firmware like DD-WRT that will often fix it. If you live in a country with decent consumer protection laws you nay be able to argue the provided device is not fitvfor purpose and get a different model.  My prference would be a simple ONT and my own router though.

Comment: Well, the ISP is the biggest one in my country and their ONT router is completely locked. I am guessing we don't have strong laws about such things. So, can't really do anything about it except either rebooting every other day or using my own router in router mode.